# Possible to add custom metrics to Back testing?

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

Is it possible to display your own calculated metrics to the back testing result in Trading View? Or write to file while executing? I would like to extract number of days Close > Open after a Buy signal for each run of a set of parameter.

I am thinking of manipulating the existing metrics (initial Capital, number of trades) as a work around but it feels like the wrong way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can display your metric to the back testing result.
You can try to use comment from your entry order. 
You can use table to display data on the chart :

```
var table controle = table.new(position=position.top_right, columns=2, rows=9)
table.cell(controle, 0, 7, "candle", text_color=color.white)
table.cell(controle, 1, 7, str.tostring(math.round(bar_index,0)), text_color=color.white)
```

You will get this type of display :

[image]

Comment: My specific need is to count the bars that moves in the predicted direction and sort my tested parameters on that percentage of all bars. I guess the easiest way is to trigger a long trade over bars that are correct and look at the percentage of bars that were spent in the market.

Comment: @Paddy it is a all new question, please create a new one. Don't forget to accept this answer if it has helped you.